# Conditionally enable form type in Symfony 2/3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.2

I have 2 form type that display 2 selects

```
    $builder
        ->add('control1', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'Country',
            'class' => Country::class,
        ])
        ->add('control2', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'State',
            'class' => State::class,
        ])
```

then in the twig template

```
        {{ form_row(form.control1)}}
        {{ form_row(form.control2)}}
```

How can I enable control2 only if a specific option is selected in control 1? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)

> You want to customize the form specific to the data that was submitted by the user. For example, imagine you have a registration form for sports gatherings. Some events will allow you to specify your preferred position on the field. This would be a choice field for example. However, the possible choices will depend on each sport. You will need the correct options in order for validation to pass.

The following example create a form with two fields, `country` and `state`. The `state` field depends on the `country` field and will remain disabled with no choices available if no country has been selected.

**Form Type**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Country;
use AppBundle\Entity\State;

class CountryStateType extends AbstractType
{
  private $entityManager;
  private $countryRepository;
  private $stateRepository;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
  {
    $this->entityManager     = $entityManager;
    $this->countryRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(Country::class);
    $this->stateRepository   = $entityManager->getRepository(State::class);
  }
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('country', EntityType::class, [
      'class' => Country::class,
      'placeholder' => 'Select',
      'choice_label' => 'name',
      'label' => 'Country'
    ]);

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $countryId = null) {
      $country  = null === $countryId ? null : $this->countryRepository->find($countryId);
      $states   = null === $country ? [] : $this->stateRepository->findAll();
      $disabled = null === $country ? true : false;

      $form->add('state', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => State::class,
        'placeholder' => 'Select',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'label' => 'State',
        'choices' => $states,
        'disabled' => $disabled
      ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
      function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $data = null === $data ? [] : $data;
        $countryId = array_key_exists('country', $data) ? $data['country'] : null;

        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $countryId);
      }
    );

    $builder->get('country')
      ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, 
      function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
        $countryId = null === $country ? null : $country->getId();

        $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent() , $countryId);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}         
  {{ form_widget(form.country) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.state) }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var $country = $('#{{ form.country.vars.id }}');
  $country.change(function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    var data = {};
    data[$country.attr('name')] = $country.val();

    $.ajax({
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      data: data,
      success: function (html) {
        $('#{{ form.state.vars.id }}').replaceWith(
          $(html).find('#{{ form.state.vars.id }}')
        );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```